# Need api to check repository permissions for git in azure devops +rest api

Tags: git, azure, azure-devops-rest-api

I need to know whether we have an API to check repository permissions for git in azure devops + rest api.

I need an API which could give me the data ..for the path shown below:

Path:
Azure Devops --->Project--->Project settings--->repositories -->Security for all Git repositories

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid that there no such directly rest api provided can achieve all of the security of groups. Since these groups which under different repository has different configuration, so we could not use one directly api to get all of these info. This is a complex operation.

Though these api does not documented, if you still want to use api to get these info, here I suggest you can track these apis from `Network` through press `F12` in pages.

[image]

Open the Repositories permission setting page, press F12 to track api.

As test, I have been get some:

```
https://dev.azure.com/{org name}/{project name}/_api/_security/DisplayPermissions?__v=5&tfid={tfid}&permissionSetId=2e9eb7ed-3c0a-47d4-87c1-0ffdd275fd87&permissionSetToken=repoV2%2F0xxxxxxxe7475323
```

Note: The `permissionSetId` are consistent, so just need to change the `tfid` and the `permissionSetToken` according to your repos.

Since this api does not documented, you can raise one suggest on our [support community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21) and PG team will consider this feature suggestion.

Comment: what is tfid do we have any reference documentation about tfid and permissionSetToken in rest api link from microsoft

Comment: The Azure DevOps api is wrapped in a PowerShell module and has commands for security namespaces: 
https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/AzurePipelinesPS